# Delayed database updates in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a crawler that goes around grabbing data. Once finished, it Posts the results as Json to a PHP endpoint. The problem is, there could be thousands of crawlers pushing data to this endpoint. Which means it must be fast and not be slowed down by things like Database queries.

Therefore, I have thought that the process of receiving the data should not include data processing, only storing. I.e. Save to disk, and processed later by a cron job on the server. That way, the upload isn't slowed down by the actual indexing process (i.e. lots of SQL statements). These statements can be executed at any time, and therefore as long as I store them, I can easily create a queue that does the actually hard work after receiving the data, as long as I run those queries sequentially.

1. Is there perhaps an inherent way to run mysql queries so that the mysql server perhaps queues it and executes them at a later stage?
2. If not, is straight to disk as sql queries the fastest way to create a queue that a cron job can manually execute afterwards?

The idea is to eventually have a single server that receives the data and another that processes it. So it would be nice to find a solution that keeps that in mind. (i.e. if I save straight to disk, how will that effect the data needing to get to the server that will process it?)

Comment: Can you try this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-delayed.html

Comment: However, it's being deprecated. Sorry. "As of MySQL 5.6.6, INSERT DELAYED is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release."